# Picture Box, Image loading

Tags: c#, winforms, image, xna, picturebox

Adding the Windows Form template to my full game as a way to read a text file when ever its called. I add a picture box to the form and what comes up is `Value cannot be null. Parameter name: docData` I looked around the Interwebs and it seems to be a problem with XNA (4.0) and how its missing things that make picture box work. How do I work around this to add a image to the picture box?

I will start from the beginning. I create a Windows Game(4.0), name it `PictureBox`. I add the `Windows Form`, name that `Form1.cs`. I add in the picture box. I then open up the properties menu, click on Image and it gives me the null. I have done nothing yet, but still this error happens.

Comment: provide some code, you just pass null to docData argument of some class constructor or method

Comment: XNA and winforms is not the same...

Comment: I don't think I said that, I did not mean it if that is what your saying. I said that I added winforms and by using XNA as the base line for my code that winforms is being affected. I want to know what is happening to winforms and why I cant use the picture box that should work. If you are talking about how I said that XNA is doing something to `PictureBox`, I was talking about how it was effecting it and not having things that would be in a Windows Form if it was the main class. Not Windows Game(4.0).